# Using styleVision Get the error "the content model of complex type definition ' anonymous ' "

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, altova, stylevision

Hi i am using the StyleVision tool. I am validating the xml files against XSD. WHen i run it says "the content model of complex type definition ' anonymous ' ". But my XML file validates against the XSD. What am i doing wrong kindly correct me. My XML and XSD is given below

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <data>
    <veterinarian>ericsamule</veterinarian>
    <clinic>Clinical Demo    Account- Full Circle Oncology</clinic> 
   <address>asd</address> 
   <phone>55555</phone>
   <date_of_service>2017-01-03</date_of_service>   
   <received_date>2017-01-01</received_date>
   <final_date>2017-01-19</final_date>
   <sample_type>F_dsds</sample_type>
   <accession_id>A-123454</accession_id>
   <lab_id>H-456123</lab_id>
   <panel_notes>cat male</panel_notes>
   <patient>CatCaty</patient>
   <gender>M</gender>
   <dob>1990-01-01</dob>
   <species>Human</species>
  </data>
```

XSD

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="veterinarian" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="clinic" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="phone" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="date_of_service" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="received_date" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="final_date" type="xs:date"/>
            <xs:element name="sample_type"  type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="accession_id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="lab_id" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="panel_notes" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="patient" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="gender" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="dob" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="species" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have cut off the end of your error message; what you've posted is merely a reference rather than a complete statement.

Nevertheless, the phrase ***the content model of complex type definition 'anonymous'*** refers to an unnamed type definition, which, in your case, is:

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="veterinarian" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="clinic" type="xs:string"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is contrasted with a *named* type definition such as

```
<xs:complexType name="DataType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="veterinarian" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="clinic" type="xs:string"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

which could be referenced like this:

```
<xs:element name="data" type="DataType"/>
```

Hopefully this explanation of what is meant by *anonymous* helps you understand the rest of your error message.  If not, please update your question with the complete error message and any supplemental files that someone knowledgeable in StyleVision would need to help you further.

Comment: Thats the complete error. " The content of complex type definition '{anonymous}' is 'empty'   "

Comment: No, that was not the complete error: In your question, the "is empty" part is left off -- that's why I asked.

Comment: That error message, even corrected, does not make sense with the XSD and XML you've posted.  Sorry, but you've likely left something else out (in addition to the tail end of the error message).

Comment: Now thats the Complete error " cvc-assess-elt.1: Neither an element declaration nor a type definition is known for element <data>. Strict assessment failed. "